# Scipy Optimize : SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Tags: numpy, optimization, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I could not figure out why i am getting this error. SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument. Error is pointing to line SLSQP_result=optimize.minimize(lambda x: obj(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9]), method='SLSQP',initial_guess, bounds=bnds,constraints=cons) in the below code.

```
obj = lambdify([A,Iz,Iy,J,kz,ky,Zc,Yc,Zg,Yg], numpy.linalg.det(K_P_modal-K_modal))

initial_guess=[5.0,0.1,0.1,5.0,0.001,0.001,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
bnds = ((0.01, 10.0),(0.001, 5.0), (0.001, 5.0),(1, 100.0),(0.0001, 2),(0.0001, 2),(0.0, 1.0),(0.0, 1),(0.0, 1),(0.0, 1))
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: K_P_modal_diag[0]-846540},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: K_P_modal_diag[0]-K_P_modal_diag[1]},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: K_P_modal_diag[1]-K_P_modal_diag[2]},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: K_P_modal_diag[2]-K_P_modal_diag[3]},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: K_P_modal_diag[3]-K_P_modal_diag[4]},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: K_P_modal_diag[4]-K_P_modal_diag[5]},{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: K_P_modal_diag[5]-K_P_modal_diag[6]},{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: K_P_modal_diag[11]-0})
SLSQP_result=optimize.minimize(lambda x: obj(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9]), method='SLSQP',initial_guess, bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am new to python. I know i am making a silly error which results in the syntax error. But i could not figure it out. Please help.

Comment: ```...method='SLSQP',initial_guess,...``` + ```SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument``` should be enough of a hint. If that's unclear, please read python's docs on how ordering of arguments matters here (swap these two).

Comment: Sascha, I modified by keeping the initial guess ahead of the method. Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Comment: Also, i have a question regarding a diagonal matrix optimization. I have posted this question yesterday but no one responded it till now. Could you help me with the optimization problem posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962214/n-by-n-symbolic-matrix-optimization-to-match-a-known-diagonal-matrix.

Comment: To be honest. It's not a great question for SO (read the tour/rules of this site; also the close-votes) and referencing it here is not what you should do. It's a bunch of unformated text and a pretty informal description of a math-problem which could be described much more compact. Additionally there is tons of ugly (it's just an opinion) code you force us to read through. Additionally, i wonder if it's a good idea to mix scipy and sympy when someone is *that* new to python.

Comment: I am so sorry. I did not had any other option that's the reason.

Comment: The better the question, the higher the probability getting help. Polluting the spam-section here with other problems is not how it works here. If people don't think your question is clearly stated (again: tour & see other questions), some have the right to express that through votes or close-calls.

Comment: I have converted the sympy to numpy using the lamdify function. The place i am stuck in this optimization is how to give the relevant constraint if the desired output is a diagonal matrix. The symbolic matrix is dense whereas the known matrix is diagonal. So it will be tiresome to give the constraint one by one for a large matrix say 1314 by 1314 size. For example, K[i,j]=0 for i!=j (i.e., all off diagonal terms are zero). What should be a quick and easy way to give the constraint for this problem?

Comment: Sascha, As per your suggestion i have updated the question in my previous post (as per the above link). I have removed the use of Sympy for the symbolic matrix and instead i have used Numpy. Now the run is much more efficient. But the error seen on the off diagonal terms is little high though. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: Please keep your discussion per topic. Don't cross-refer. In terms of your other question, follow Erwin's advice. Mathematical-model first or it's hard to get what you are doing.